# How to print multidimensional array in two different html table in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, html-table

Here my array:

```
Array
(
    [status] => OK
    [result] => Array
        (
            [pnr] => 4106121148
            [cls] => SL
            [eticket] => 1
            [journey] => 17-Apr-2015
            [trainno] => 16629
            [name] => MALABAR EXP
            [from] => CNGR
            [to] => MAQ
            [brdg] => CNGR
            [passengers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [bookingstatus] => S10  41GN
                            [currentstatus] => CNF
                            [coach] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [bookingstatus] => S10  42GN
                            [currentstatus] => CNF
                            [coach] => 
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [bookingstatus] => S10  43GN
                            [currentstatus] => CNF
                            [coach] => 
                        )

                )

            [chart] => CHART NOT PREPARED
            [error] => 
        )

)
```

I try to print this to two different html table tr.

```
if($responseArray['status'] === 'OK') {

        $pnr= '<tr>';
        $pnr.= '<td>'.$responseArray['result']['pnr'].'</td>';
        $pnr.= '<td>'.$responseArray['result']['journey'].'</td>';
        $pnr.= '<td>'.$responseArray['result']['name'].'</td>';
        $pnr.= '<td>'.$responseArray['result']['trainno'].'</td>';
        $pnr.= '<td>'.$responseArray['result']['cls'].'</td>';
        $pnr.= '<td>'.$responseArray['result']['from'].'</td>';
        $pnr.= '<td>'.$responseArray['result']['brdg'].'</td>';
        $pnr.= '<td>'.$responseArray['result']['to'].'</td>';
        $pnr.= '<td>'.$responseArray['result']['chart'].'</td>';
        $pnr.= '</tr>';

       $i=0;
       foreach($responseArray['result']['passengers'] as $passengers){
            $i++;
            $psngr='<tr>';
            $psngr.= '<td>Pasenger No '.$i;.'</td>';
            $psngr.= '<td>'.$passengers['bookingstatus'].'</td>';
            $psngr.= '<td>'.$passengers['currentstatus'].'</td>';
            $psngr.='</tr>';
        }

        echo $pnr.'#'.$psngr;
}
```

I concatenate two table tr string and print. First string (`$pnr`) prints fine. In second string (`$psngr`) I have three values but print last value only i.e.

```
<tr><td>Pasenger No 3</td><td>S10  43GN</td><td>CNF</td></tr>
```

It should be

```
<tr><td>Pasenger No 1</td><td>S10  41GN</td><td>CNF</td></tr>
<tr><td>Pasenger No 2</td><td>S10  42GN</td><td>CNF</td></tr>
<tr><td>Pasenger No 3</td><td>S10  43GN</td><td>CNF</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your table row variable with each iteration. Change the code to the following should work (note the foreach part):

```
if($responseArray['status'] === 'OK') {

    $pnr= '<tr>';
    $pnr.= '<td>'.$responseArray['result']['pnr'].'</td>';
    $pnr.= '<td>'.$responseArray['result']['journey'].'</td>';
    $pnr.= '<td>'.$responseArray['result']['name'].'</td>';
    $pnr.= '<td>'.$responseArray['result']['trainno'].'</td>';
    $pnr.= '<td>'.$responseArray['result']['cls'].'</td>';
    $pnr.= '<td>'.$responseArray['result']['from'].'</td>';
    $pnr.= '<td>'.$responseArray['result']['brdg'].'</td>';
    $pnr.= '<td>'.$responseArray['result']['to'].'</td>';
    $pnr.= '<td>'.$responseArray['result']['chart'].'</td>';
    $pnr.= '</tr>';

   $i=0;
   $psngr = '';
   foreach($responseArray['result']['passengers'] as $passengers){
        $i++;
        $psngr.='<tr>';
        $psngr.= '<td>Pasenger No '.$i;.'</td>';
        $psngr.= '<td>'.$passengers['bookingstatus'].'</td>';
        $psngr.= '<td>'.$passengers['currentstatus'].'</td>';
        $psngr.='</tr>';
    }

    echo $pnr.'#'.$psngr;
}
```

Comment: same result @tworabbits

Comment: I actually can not imagine that you get the same result :) And another question is: What exactly does the hash stands for when your print your table?

Comment: <tr><td>4106121148</td><td>17-Apr-2015</td><td>MALABAR EXP</td><td>16629</td><td>SL</td><td>CNGR</td><td>CNGR</td><td>MAQ</td><td>CHART NOT PREPARED</td></tr>#<tr><td>Passenger No3</td><td>S10  43GN</td><td>CNF</td></tr>

Comment: Do you use pure php or is your code run by a library which might cache your output?

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
$psngr .= '<tr>';
```

And put `$psngr = '';` ouside the outer loop.